# Global state in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am developing a React Native application.

I want to save the user id of the person who is logged in and then check if the user is logged in in every single component.

So what I am looking for is something like cookies, sessions or global states.

I have read that I should use Redux, but this seems to be overly complicated and it is very difficult to make it work with `react-navigation`. It forces me to define actions and reducers for almost everything although the only thing I want is to be able to access a single global state/variable in all components.

Are there any alternatives or should I really re-structure my entire app to use Redux?

Comment: I don't think having multiple stores is a sin, in whichc ase a store is something that contains a value (or object or array or whatever) and provides a change notification to all its subscribed listeners when the stored data is modified.

Comment: There are alternatives such as context variables in react components but I think in the long run you might find redux a lot more structured and easy to manage (and test). It does seem daunting at first but you'll soon realise there's not a lot to it.

Answer (score 42):

I usually create a global.js containing:

```
module.exports = {
   screen1: null,
};
```

And get the value of the state on the screen

```
import GLOBAL from './global.js'

constructor() {

    GLOBAL.screen1 = this;

}
```

Now you can use it anywhere like so:

```
GLOBAL.screen1.setState({
    var: value
});
```

Comment: This is the best; don't underestimate it for being simple. I fiddled with Redux forever just to get basically the same functionality but with 20X the code and lots of magic (the `connect` stuff is really jank).

Comment: can you put more robust explanations. I'm not sure what you're doing in the render(){Global.screen1state = this}

Comment: the simplicity is exactly what makes it a great solution @sudo

Comment: Doesn't `this` refer to the react component? If so, better name would be `GLOBAL.screen1 = this`, since this is the component and `this.state` is what actually refers to the state associated with the component. @RaphaelEstrada

Comment: Maybe I'm a React Native newb, but this works great for me!

Comment: it should be **import * as GLOBAL from './global.js'**

Comment: i am a newbie. how do you do this with function component?

Comment: I was always afraid of redux. But with this method, the problem is completely solved

Comment: how about functional component

Comment: This solution is fine for stuff like user data. But your example of storing react components in the global state to later reference is absolutely terrible and goes against everything react.

Answer (score 7):

**Update since React 16.8.0 (February 6, 2019) introduce Hooks.**

it is not mandatory to use external library like `Mobx` or `Redux`. (Before Hook was introduce I used both of this state management solutions)

you can create global state just with 10 line [Source](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
export const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) =>(
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

extend your app with global state:

```
import { StateProvider } from '../state';

const App = () => {
  const initialState = {
    theme: { primary: 'green' }
  };

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'changeTheme':
        return {
          ...state,
          theme: action.newTheme
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };


  return (
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
        // App content ...
    </StateProvider>
  );
}
```

For details explanation I recommend to read this wonderful [medium](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)

Comment: Context is for ReactJS.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do globals like this:

I creat an globals.js

```
module.exports = {
  USERNAME: '',
};
```

Something like that to store the username then you just need to import :

```
GLOBAL = require('./globals');
```

And if you wanna store the Data, lets say you want to save the username just do :

```
var username = 'test';
GLOBAL.USERNAME = username;
```

And there you go , you just need to import GLOBAL on the pages you want and use it, just use `if (GLOBAL.username == 'teste')`.

Comment: this way is not working properly and not trigger the changes like this.state

Comment: This way is partially good. It's only good for storing things that mostly remain constant (logged in state for example). Particularly because changing this stuff won't re-render the component (could clone the props though).

Answer (score 4):

There are some [alternatives to Redux](https://medium.com/@machnicki/why-redux-is-not-so-easy-some-alternatives-24816d5ad22d) in terms of state management. I would recommend you to look at Jumpsuit and Mobx. However do not expect them to be easier than Redux. State management is mostly a magical thing and most of the gizmo happens behind the scenes.

But anyways if you feel that you need some global state management, it worths your time to master one of the solutions no matter Redux or Mobx or etc. I would not recommend using `AsyncStorage` or anything hacky for this purpose.

Comment: Components like `AsyncStorage` are for persistence, I think the OP is concerned with managing the state of the app which generally should be in memory.

Comment: @sooper , that is why I am not recommending ```AsyncStorage```.

Comment: State management isn't magical by nature. It can be super simple while being maximally effective without being behind the scenes whatsoever, see the above answer by @RaphaelEstrada. You're recommending using an entire library of code, most of which you will never use, when *a single javascript object can do the job just as effectively.*

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to react (as me) and got confused by the first answer.
First, use a component Class

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    walk: true
  };
  GLOBAL.screen1 = this;
}

render() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
      {this.state.walk ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="WalkThrough" component={WalkThroughScreen} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </NavigationContainer>
 )
}
```

Then you can do in any other component (My components are on /components, global is on root):

```
import GLOBAL from '../global.js'

GLOBAL.screen1.setState({walk:false})
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question but I have a solution that helps me.

To accomplish this, I use what is called a GlobalProvider, essentially provides global data to all components. A lot of this code was learned through YouTube Tutorials so I can not take credit for the ideas. Here is the code,

```
export const GlobalContext = createContext({});

const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {
    //authInitialState can be whatever you want, ex: {rand: {}, rand2: null}
    const [authState, authDispatch] = useReducer(auth, authInitialState);

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider
            value={{authState, authDispatch}}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default GlobalProvider;
```

Then you would simply wrap your entire application (usually app.js) with GlobalProvider as so. Ignore my AppNavContainer, that just contains code that routes my pages.

```
import GlobalProvider from "./src/Context/Provider";
const App: () => Node = () => {
    return (
        <GlobalProvider>
            <AppNavContainer/>
        </GlobalProvider>
    );
};
```

From here on you are able to change the authState with a reducer of some sort, I will not provide that code since it is huge, but look at Soullivaneuh's example on the reducer above.

NOW to the good part, of how to access your state. It is simple, in any component you wish, simply follow a similar structure like this. Notice that I have {data} as it will allow you to see the state.

```
    const {
        authState: {data},
    } = useContext(GlobalContext);
    
    console.log("Data:", data)
```

If anyone can correct me where I went wrong, I'd appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a GLOBAL object. If set in app.js as GLOBAL.user = user, it appears to be available in other components, such as the drawer navigation.